# tgkill - Native Crash for Samsung Devices in Android 8.0

Tags: android, native, android-8.0-oreo, samsung-galaxy

We are observing a native crash on Samsung devices with Android 8.0 in Play Console for our app.
We have never been able to reproduce this crash ourselves.

The crash is occurring in the following devices

Galaxy S7(herolte) Galaxy S8(dreamlte) Galaxy A5(2017) Galaxy
    A7(2018) Galaxy S9+ (star2LTE) Galaxy A7(2017) Galaxy S7 edge
    (hero2lte)

The backtrace is

```
#00  pc 000000000006b488  /system/lib64/libc.so (tgkill+8)
  #01  pc 000000000001dbd0  /system/lib64/libc.so (abort+88)
  #02  pc 00000000004380f8  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art7Runtime5AbortEPKc+528)
  #03  pc 0000000000438808  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art7Runtime7AborterEPKc+24)
  #04  pc 000000000052383c  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN7android4base10LogMessageD1Ev+900)
  #05  pc 00000000004628fc  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZNK3art6Thread24AssertNoPendingExceptionEv+1144)
  #06  pc 0000000000128120  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11ClassLinker9FindClassEPNS_6ThreadEPKcNS_6HandleINS_6mirror11ClassLoaderEEE+64)
  #07  pc 0000000000311364  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art3JNI9FindClassEP7_JNIEnvPKc+1432)
  #08  pc 000000000002bed8  /system/lib64/libjavacrypto.so (_ZN9conscrypt6Errors24jniThrowRuntimeExceptionEP7_JNIEnvPKc+40)
  #09  pc 000000000002c7a0  /system/lib64/libjavacrypto.so (_ZN9conscrypt6Errors25throwExceptionIfNecessaryEP7_JNIEnvPKcPFiS2_S4_E+732)
  #10  pc 000000000001ff8c  /system/lib64/libjavacrypto.so (_ZL29NativeCrypto_d2i_X509_CRL_bioP7_JNIEnvP7_jclassl+56)
  #11  pc 000000000002de78  /system/framework/arm64/boot-conscrypt.oat (com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.PEM_read_bio_PUBKEY [DEDUPED]+152)
  #12  pc 0000000000509038  /system/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_static_stub+600)
  #13  pc 00000000000d7fd8  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art9ArtMethod6InvokeEPNS_6ThreadEPjjPNS_6JValueEPKc+260)
  #14  pc 00000000002826b0  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter34ArtInterpreterToCompiledCodeBridgeEPNS_6ThreadEPNS_9ArtMethodEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemEPNS_11ShadowFrameEPNS_6JValueE+352)
  #15  pc 000000000027cd78  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter6DoCallILb0ELb0EEEbPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE+672)
  #16  pc 00000000004f1c04  /system/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeStatic+468)
  #17  pc 00000000004fa994  /system/lib64/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+14612)
  #18  pc 000000000025daf4  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb+444)
  #19  pc 00000000004e4560  /system/lib64/libart.so (artQuickToInterpreterBridge+1468)
  #20  pc 000000000051221c  /system/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_to_interpreter_bridge+92)
  #21  pc 0000000000057814  /system/framework/arm64/boot-conscrypt.oat (com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLX509CertificateFactory$2.fromX509DerInputStream+52)
  #22  pc 00000000000575e0  /system/framework/arm64/boot-conscrypt.oat (com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLX509CertificateFactory$1.fromX509DerInputStream [DEDUPED]+48)
  #23  pc 0000000000056ef0  /system/framework/arm64/boot-conscrypt.oat (com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLX509CertificateFactory$Parser.generateItem+944)
  #24  pc 0000000000057b9c  /system/framework/arm64/boot-conscrypt.oat (com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLX509CertificateFactory.engineGenerateCRL+76)
  #25  pc 00000000003c0e34  /system/framework/arm64/boot.oat (java.security.cert.CertificateFactory.generateCRL+68)
  #26  pc 0000000000508d84  /system/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+580)
  #27  pc 00000000000d7f9c  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art9ArtMethod6InvokeEPNS_6ThreadEPjjPNS_6JValueEPKc+200)
  #28  pc 00000000002826b0  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter34ArtInterpreterToCompiledCodeBridgeEPNS_6ThreadEPNS_9ArtMethodEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemEPNS_11ShadowFrameEPNS_6JValueE+352)
  #29  pc 000000000027cd78  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter6DoCallILb0ELb0EEEbPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE+672)
  #30  pc 00000000004f3804  /system/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtualQuick+680)
  #31  pc 00000000004fe594  /system/lib64/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+29972)
  #32  pc 000000000025daf4  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb+444)
  #33  pc 00000000004e4560  /system/lib64/libart.so (artQuickToInterpreterBridge+1468)
  #34  pc 000000000051221c  /system/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_to_interpreter_bridge+92)
  #35  pc 00000000003bf7c4  /system/framework/arm64/boot.oat (java.security.cert.CertStore.getCRLs+68)
  #36  pc 0000000000508d84  /system/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+580)
  #37  pc 00000000000d7f9c  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art9ArtMethod6InvokeEPNS_6ThreadEPjjPNS_6JValueEPKc+200)
  #38  pc 00000000002826b0  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter34ArtInterpreterToCompiledCodeBridgeEPNS_6ThreadEPNS_9ArtMethodEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemEPNS_11ShadowFrameEPNS_6JValueE+352)
  #39  pc 000000000027cd78  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter6DoCallILb0ELb0EEEbPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE+672)
  #40  pc 00000000004f3804  /system/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtualQuick+680)
  #41  pc 00000000004fe594  /system/lib64/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+29972)
  #42  pc 000000000025daf4  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb+444)
  #43  pc 00000000002641f4  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter33ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridgeEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemEPNS_11ShadowFrameEPNS_6JValueE+212)
  #44  pc 000000000027dbc8  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter6DoCallILb1ELb0EEEbPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE+584)
  #45  pc 00000000004f34ac  /system/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeStaticRange+396)
  #46  pc 00000000004fac94  /system/lib64/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+15380)
  #47  pc 000000000025daf4  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb+444)
  #48  pc 00000000002641f4  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter33ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridgeEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemEPNS_11ShadowFrameEPNS_6JValueE+212)
  #49  pc 000000000027dbc8  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter6DoCallILb1ELb0EEEbPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE+584)
  #50  pc 00000000004f34ac  /system/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeStaticRange+396)
  #51  pc 00000000004fac94  /system/lib64/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+15380)
  #52  pc 000000000025daf4  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb+444)
  #53  pc 00000000004e4560  /system/lib64/libart.so (artQuickToInterpreterBridge+1468)
  #54  pc 000000000051221c  /system/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_to_interpreter_bridge+92)
  #55  pc 00000000007aaccc  /system/framework/arm64/boot.oat (sun.security.provider.certpath.RevocationChecker.checkCRLs+2684)
  #56  pc 00000000007a95f4  /system/framework/arm64/boot.oat (sun.security.provider.certpath.RevocationChecker.check+1892)
  #57  pc 00000000007adf40  /system/framework/arm64/boot.oat (sun.security.provider.certpath.RevocationChecker.check+112)
  #58  pc 000000000079c998  /system/framework/arm64/boot.oat (sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXMasterCertPathValidator.validate+2152)
  #59  pc 000000000079b050  /system/framework/arm64/boot.oat (sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXCertPathValidator.validate+3376)
  #60  pc 000000000079bc34  /system/framework/arm64/boot.oat (sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXCertPathValidator.validate+1556)
  #61  pc 000000000079c0ec  /system/framework/arm64/boot.oat (sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXCertPathValidator.engineValidate+380)
  #62  pc 0000000000508d84  /system/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+580)
  #63  pc 00000000000d7f9c  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art9ArtMethod6InvokeEPNS_6ThreadEPjjPNS_6JValueEPKc+200)
```

The issue seems to be some where in the certificate validation and the classes related to Conscrypt are also visible which is the Java Security Provider. Has Any body faced this issue before and can help in understanding this backtrace.